# Condition with multiple columns in DAX

Tags: filter, dax

can I somehow filter in DAX with multiple columns?

I need filter that the difference between two dates are lower than 300 days like below.

```
EVALUATE
(
    CALCULATETABLE
    (
        SUMMARIZE
        (
            'Sales',
            'Sales'[MaxDatum],
            'Sales'[MinDatum]
        ),
        INT('Sales'[MaxDatum] - 'Sales'[MinDatum]) < 300            
    )
)
```

So it failed with this error:

> The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can
>   be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter
>   expression.

I tried another construction of that query like this, but in this case I cannot reuse the calculated member.

```
EVALUATE
(
    CALCULATETABLE
    (
        SUMMARIZE
        (
            'Sales',
            'Sales'[MaxDatum],
            'Sales'[MinDatum],
            "DIFF", INT('Sales'[MinDatum] - 'Sales'[MaxDatum]) 
        ),
        [DIFF] < 300        
    )
)
```

Is possible to do this somehow in DAX query?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EVALUATE
 (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS ( Sales, "Diff", 1 * ( Sales[MaxDatum] - Sales[MinDatum] ) ),
        [Diff] < 300
    )
)
```

If you are using SSAS 2016, Excel 2016 or Power BI you can use the `DATEDIFF` function which is a more reliable way to calculate time deltas.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's works correctly but what is the reason to add "1 *" into that query?

Comment: @Bushwacka, the 1* is an implicit data conversion, basically I am converting the difference between both dates in an integer. You can use also `INT()` function.